# undifined sized string split in c without strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I have a string:

```
 char *s = "asdf:jhgf";
```

I need to split this into two tokens:

```
token[0] = "asdf";
token[1] = "jhgf";
```

I'm having problems with `strtok()`.

Comment: `strtok not working.` what you have tried?

Comment: Read about [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr). Or just use a loop?

Comment: `size of string not predefined`  You can get the string length with `strlen`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410280/how-to-split-string-in-c-without-using-strtok

Comment: if you were trying to do `strtok` on a string literal... don't do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `sscanf()`:

```
char token[2][80];

if(sscanf(s, "%[^:]:%s", token[0], token[1]) == 2)
{
  printf("token 0='%s'\ntoken 1='%s'\n", token[0], token[1]);
}
```

Note that the first conversion is done using `%[^:]` to scan up until (but not including) the colon. Then we skip the colon, and scan an ordinary string.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Because I haven't finished my coffee yet. :) I'll fix, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *s = "asdf:jhgf";
    char *token[2];
    char *p = strchr(s, ':');
    size_t len1 = p-s, len2 = strlen(p+1);
    token[0] = malloc(len1+1);
    token[1] = malloc(len2+1);
    memcpy(token[0], s, len1);
    token[0][len1]=0;
    memcpy(token[1], p+1, len2+1);
    puts(token[0]);
    puts(token[1]);
    free(token[0]);free(token[1]);
    return 0;
}
```